# c# mvc5 pass more than one list, object, ... from controller to view

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

i can send one database fetch result as a list from controller to view by using this method:

```
var all_companies = db_cnx.Db.tbl_company.ToList();
var all_contractors = db_cnx.Db.tbl_contractor.toList();

return View(all_companies);
```

but how can i send more than one objects or list , ... to view?
like:

```
return view(all_companies, all_contractors)
```

is this possible?
i read a comment that said you must declare one ViewItem and store the combination of vars in it and return new data set but how?

Comment: Look for a concept called ViewModel

Answer (score 2):

To `View` you can return only one class.

You have to create a model class with those lists and pass that model.

```
public class MyModel {
   public List<Company> Companies {get;set;}
   public List<Contractor> Contractors {get;set; }
}
```

---

```
var all_companies = db_cnx.Db.tbl_company.ToList();
var all_contractors = db_cnx.Db.tbl_contractor.toList();
var model = new MyModel {
    Companies = all_companies,
    Contractos = all_contractors
}

return View(model);
```

---

In View you are using your model instead of lists like that:

```
@model MyModel
```

and usage:

```
@Model.Companies 
@Model.Contractors
```